# SQL server JOIN much slower than equivalent WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two tables, test_table and timeseries_table

The test_table has Test_id column, the start and end times (big int) of the test run and a channel_id. the timeseries_table has timestamp of each individual observation, the measurement value, and a channel_id.

I've constructed a case where the same query is constructed via a join, and a WHERE with the values that would be applied to the join.

Query 1 is effectively

```
SELECT * FROM timeseries_table 
WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) 
AND channel_id = 5
```

Query 2 is effectively

```
SELECT * FROM timeseries_table A JOIN test_table B 
ON (A.timestamp BETWEEN B.start_time AND B.end_time) 
AND A.channel_id = B.channel_id
WHERE B.test_id = 8
```

Where query test_id =8 in query 2 returns a single row from that table with the values used in query 1.

Query 1 takes 100ms, query 2 takes 6 seconds. The single row query for the line used for the where clause takes 4ms.

The queries both return the same number of rows of the same data (verified all rows and all columns)

What could explain this huge time difference been queries?

I was expecting the join to be a similar speed to the where clause

Comment: Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)s for the 2 queries?

Comment: Those are two entirely different queries which would produce non-similiar query plans. Can you take a look at the query plan generated by both? In the first query your range is known ahead of time 1000-2000.

Comment: *"The queries both return the same number of rows of the same data (verified all rows and all columns)"* Impossible. YOur first query returns all columns from `timeseries_table`, your second returns all columns from **both** `timeseries_table` *and* `test_table`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the plan itself due to being on a non-comnected network. What am i I looking for in the plan?

Comment: My bad, I meant I have verified the mutual columns of both queries to be identical

Comment: In query 1 93% of the cost is a clustered index scan of the timerseries_table. In query 2 87% of the cost is a key lookup (clustered) of the same table

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a covering index in either scenario.

Comment: As a side note, calling a column `timestamp` and comparing it to `int` values or a columns called `start_time` and `end_time` is *very* confusing. `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion` which is `binary(8)` value. You then compare that to `int` values, which isn't going to work as you expect. MOre confusing is you compare to columns called `start_time`, but there is a `time` data type, which presumably your `start_time` and `end_time` columns are. So you have a `binary(8)` compared to both `int` and `time` values? The former'll give unexpected results and the latter will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences between those queries that will lead to differences in query execution.  If you know that there's only a single start_time and end_time, and you want the query plan to be able to use the runtime parameter values in the query plan optimization, do this:

```
declare @start_time int, @end_time int

select @start_time = start_time, @end_time = end_time
from test_table 
where test_id = 8

SELECT * FROM timeseries_table A 
WHERE A.timestamp BETWEEN @start_time AND @end_time
option (recompile)
```

If you have a few values from test_table you want to use, and you want a plan similar to the one with the parameters, try something like this:

```
select A.*
from test_table tt
cross apply
(
    select * 
    from timeseries_table A
    where A.start_time between tt.start_time and tt.end_time 
) A
```

Comment: Hi David, Unfortunately I need to be able to expand the query to multiple criteria and multiple values later on, ideally maintaining the performance of the first query

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are in need of some indexes. Please be careful when adding indexes because it can make your database larger and actually slow down insert, update and deletes.

I would suggest an index on time_series on channel_id and timestamp.

I would suggest an index on test_table on test_id, channel_id, start_time and end_time.

For Example

```
Create Index idx_TimeSeries_ChannelId_TimeStamp On time_series(channel_id, timestamp)

Create Index idx_TestTable_TestId_ChannelId On test_table(test_id, channel_id, start_time, endTime)
```

If you can... create the index and compare the performance. If you decide to keep the indexes, that's fine. If it does not improve performance, you should probably remove the indexes.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to reduce the query time of query 2 to 120ms, though I still don't entirely understand how.

The fix for this was LEFT JOIN on query 2 rather than just JOIN.